# Default color palette MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, colors

Does anyone have an idea how to change (or add colors to) the default color palette in MS Word (2003)? I want to add the company colors in it, for ease of use.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news first:

There is no way to change the default palettes in word.

But all is not lost, you can create a macro that will put your color on highlighted text.  The steps are below:

Go to **Tools** > **Macro** > **Record New Macro**

If you want it to be available to all documents use the current settings and type in a name that will remind you of what color it is.

Click **OK**.

Go to **Format** > **Font** and then select **Font Color** then **More colors...** (Meer kleuren... :) and **Custom**.  Type in the RGB values of the color and click **OK**, then **OK** again and then click on the **Stop** button that is showing on the Macro toolbar.

Highlight the text you want to change the color of and go to **Tools** > **Macro** > **Macros** and select your macro and click **Run**.  The text will change to that color.

You can assign the macros you create to either a new toolbar or existing toolbars or give them keyboard shortcuts.